# Spherical Bessel Function Relations

Tags: sequences-and-series, bessel-functions

I have a question regarding the spherical Bessel functions. Two standard relations in the literature are

$$\sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty} (2\ell + 1) j_{\ell}^{2}(x) = 1$$

$$\sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty} (2\ell + 1) [j'_{\ell}(x)]^{2} = {1 \over 3}$$

However, I cannot find their derivation. I need to calculate higher order analogs of these relations such as

$$\sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty} (2\ell + 1) [j''_{\ell}(x)]^{2} = f(x)$$

etc, where $f(x)$ is possibly some function of $x$. I am not sure where to start. I would be much obliged if somebody could suggest a way forward, maybe by explaining how the first two relations are derived. I have tried using the recursion relations, which swap derivatives for products of $\ell$, $\ell + 1$ and $j_{\ell}$, $j'_{\ell}$. This does not seem to help though, it recasts the problem into the calculation of terms such as

$$\sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty} (2\ell + 1) \ell^{2}(\ell + 1)^{2} [j_{\ell}(x)]^{2}$$

$$\sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty} (2\ell + 1) \ell(\ell + 1) [j'_{\ell}(x)]^{2}$$

Anyway, any suggestions would be great, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General expressions can be obtained by using the [addition theorem](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.60.E2)
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\sin w}{w}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2n+1)j_{n}\left(v\right)j_{n}\left(u\right)P_{n}\left(\cos\alpha\right)
\end{equation}
where $w=\sqrt{u^2+v^2-2uv\cos\alpha}$ and $P_n$ denotes the Legendre polynomial of degree $n$. Choosing $\alpha=0$ we have $P_n(\cos\alpha)=1$ and thus
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\sin\sqrt{(u-v)^2}}{\sqrt{(u-v)^2}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2n+1)j_{n}\left(v\right)j_{n}\left(u\right)
\end{equation}
which can be written simply
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\sin(u-v)}{u-v}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2n+1)j_{n}\left(v\right)j_{n}\left(u\right)
\end{equation}
Now, by taking the limit of the above identity for $v\to u$, one obtains
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2n+1)\left[j_{n}(u)\right]^2=1
\end{equation}
If we differentiate successively the identity with respect to $u$ and to $v$,
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\sin \left(u -v \right)}{u -v}+\frac{2 \cos \left(u -v \right)}{\left(u -v \right)^{2}}-\frac{2 \sin \left(u -v \right)}{\left(u -v \right)^{3}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2n+1)j'_{n}\left(v\right)j'_{n}\left(u\right)
\end{equation}
Taking the limit for $v\to u$ we have
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2n+1)\left[j'_{n}(u)\right]^2=\frac13
\end{equation} This operation can be generalized by remarking that, to obtain the series of the $p$th derivative
\begin{equation}
 S_p=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2n+1)\left[j^{(p)}_{n}\left(u\right)\right]^2
\end{equation}
one can differentiate successively $p$ times $\sin(u-v)/(u-v)$ wrt to $u$ and to $v$ and take the limit of the result for $v\to u$
\begin{equation}
 S_p=\lim_{v\to u}\frac{\partial^{2p}}{\partial u^p\partial v^p}\frac{\sin(u-v)}{(u-v)}
\end{equation}
But, for a function $f$
\begin{align}
 \frac{\partial^{2p}}{\partial u^p\partial v^p}f(u-v)&=\left.(-1)^p\frac{\partial^{2p}}{\partial x^{2p}}f(x)\right|_{x=u-v}\\
 \lim_{v\to u}\frac{\partial^{2p}}{\partial u^p\partial v^p}f(u-v)&=\left.(-1)^p\frac{\partial^{2p}}{\partial x^{2p}}f(x)\right|_{x=0}
\end{align}
As
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\sin x}{x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k+1)!}
\end{equation}
it comes directly
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2n+1)\left[j^{(p)}_{n}\left(u\right)\right]^2=\frac{1}{2p+1}
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you so much, that is exactly what I was looking for.